# Condition failed in the function

Tags: python

I would like to create a function that take a list and sum all number in the list. For instance, in the list `["a", 1.50, 2, u'week', 250, 12]`, the function will return the output `255.50` (1.50 + 2 +250 +12).

```
def sum(list):
   sum = 0
   for item in list:
      if type(item) == 'a number'
         sum += item
   return sum
```

By what could I replace the line `if type(item) == 'a number'`?

Comment: Try this: `try: sum += float(item) except: pass`.

Comment: @ForceBru `except TypeError`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye `float()` throws a `ValueError` if you can't convert it

Comment: Using `sum` as your function name burries the builtin sum

Comment: @TemporalWolf He does not need `float`, they are already floats. Adding a float to a string gives a `TypeError`: `my_sum=0.; ... my_sum += item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
from numbers import Number

if isinstance(item, Number):
```